# jQuery: Append new object to DIV and act on that new object

Tags: jquery

I have a question that must be common but I dont know it.

If I append something (lets say SPAN) to a DIV, how can I act on that new SPAN at the same time?

```
function makeRotatable($clone) {
    $($clone).before('<span style="height:200px;"></span>').slider({
            orientation: "vertical",
            range: "min",
            min: 0,
            max: 100,
            value: 60,
            slide: function( event, ui ) {
                $( "#amount" ).val( ui.value );
            }
        });

}
```

What I want to do is act on that newly appended SPAN. But the slider is acting on the $clone instead. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`.insertBefore()`](http://api.jquery.com/insertBefore/) instead, like this:

```
function makeRotatable($clone) {
  $('<span style="height:200px;" />').slider({
        orientation: "vertical",
        range: "min",
        min: 0,
        max: 100,
        value: 60,
        slide: function( event, ui ) {
            $( "#amount" ).val( ui.value );
        }
  }).insertBefore($clone);
}
```

[`.insertBefore()`](http://api.jquery.com/insertBefore/) returns the element before it as well, but it'll be the span in this case, which is what you're after.  Also note that calling it *after* `.slider()` is a bit more efficient, since the plugin will work more quickly on a document fragment as it inserts elements.

Comment: I think the optimisation deserves a +1 :-)

Comment: thanks Nick! When I'm done with my app, I'll be sure to send you guys a link.

Answer (score 5):

Swap them around and use [*insertBefore()*](http://api.jquery.com/insertBefore/):

```
$('<span style="height:200px;"></span>').insertBefore($clone).slider({
    orientation: "vertical",
    range: "min",
    min: 0,
    max: 100,
    value: 60,
    slide: function(event, ui) {
        $("#amount").val(ui.value);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

The `before` function returns the `$($clone)` in your case. This is how jQuery's chaining works. To achieve your desired effect, chain on the newly appended SPAN instead:

```
$('<span style="height:200px;"></span>').insertBefore($($clone)).slider(...);
```

Answer (score 1):

I would try:

```
  var span = $('<span style="height:200px;"></span>').slider({
                orientation: "vertical",
                range: "min",
                min: 0,
                max: 100,
                value: 60,
                slide: function( event, ui ) {
                    $( "#amount" ).val( ui.value );
                }
            }); 
    $($clone).before(span);
```